# Opcache revalidate freq config in php.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework, config, opcache

If I'm setting this config in php.ini file:

```
opcache.revalidate_freq = 0
```

Will it still be better than disable Opcache system?

Because in my opinion, it will check for file updates every request, so it like the Opcache is disabled.

Answer (score 5):

It will check the timestamp on every request, if the timestamp is unchanged it will serve the file from cache, so you are still benefiting from the opcache.

Answer (score 2):

This is how soon opcache will check whether the php file has changed, as far as I know. I use 30 seconds:

```
opcache.revalidate_freq=30
```

what you're referring to is likely the **on / off** for that function:

```
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is providing a overhead in that the file would be checked every time it is accessed, recompiled and cached, and then served.

If Opcache was disabled, the file would just be compiled and served.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use

```
 opcache.revalidate_freq = 1
```

http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.validate-timestamps

Opache will then always validate timestamps, but in case it didn't change it can use the cached opcode.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that's what happened when the value was `0`. With a value of `1`, it won't check the timestamp on every request, it'll only re-check after `1` second has past. So, if a request comes in 500ms after a request that primed the cache, the timestamp won't be checked for the second request.